# SSL Certificate Issuing with No-IP DDNS & apache2 server & Let'sEncrypt Certbot: Conflicting info & Not working

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

The title is pretty explanatory regarding the tools I am using but I will try to elaborate further:

- I have a No-IP DDNS that is publicly accessible
- Port forwarding is configured for port 80
- The port 80 forwarding points to a Raspberry Pi that I am using as an apache2 server
- The RPi is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch) kernel 4.9.80-v7+
- I can see the contents of the `index.html` by navigating to < *DDNS-name* >:80 in a web browser using an external network
- I need to issue SSL certificates to convert to HTTPS for hosting of an Alexa skill

For the Stretch, Certbot usage is here:
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-apache

Per the link, I run:

`sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --installer apache`

and proceed through the configuration up to the verification stage, at which point I get the following:

```
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. <DDNS-name> (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://<DDNS-name>/.well-known/acme-challenge/yDloDClARe-ZW1KxiqAUSCE4ZUoNCOzpmDFvcrdx9WE: Timeout

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: <DDNS-name>
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://<DDNS-name>/.well-known/acme-challenge/yDloDClARe-ZW1KxiqAUSCE4ZUoNCOzpmDFvcrdx9WE:
   Timeout

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

I wouldn't expect any firewall issues or name issues if I can access server publicly.

I've found some interesting results regarding my issue:

- "In addition, it won’t work at all if you’re serving a website with a dynamic DNS service." - https://www.booleanworld.com/adding-https-website-lets-encrypt/
- "Do you support dynamic DNS services like No-IP?... But Let’s Encrypt supports this. So you don’t have to care about your DynDNS service." - https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dyndns-no-ip-managed-dns-support/883/6
- Not sure how to change the challenges for verification (maybe this is why it's not verifying?) - https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ddns-and-lets-encrypt/31870/2

Would appreciate any/all help on this, thanks!

EDIT: After changing DocumentRoot from `/var/www/<DDNS-name>` to `/var/www/<DDNS-name>/`, I get the following:

```
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. <DDNS-name> (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://<DDNS-name>/.well-known/acme-challenge/pdyt7okkiqgYR2YemcBfFBXf78D4cGUw6eP41BgZtsQ: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: <DDNS-name>
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://<DDNS-name>/.well-known/acme-challenge/pdyt7okkiqgYR2YemcBfFBXf78D4cGUw6eP41BgZtsQ:
   "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
   <html><head>
   <title>404 Not Found</title>
   </head><body>
   <h1>Not Found</h1>
   <p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

EDIT 2 (File structure):

```
pi@butters-pi:/var/www $ ls
<DDNS-name>
pi@butters-pi:/var/www $ cd <DDNS-name>/
pi@butters-pi:/var/www/<DDNS-name> $ ls
alexa.php  CHANGELOG.md  config.php  LICENSE  mintLib.php  public_html  README.md
pi@butters-pi:/var/www/<DDNS-name> $ cd public_html/
pi@butters-pi:/var/www/<DDNS-name>/public_html $ ls
index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much use the same setup and I can confirm that let's encrypt certbot works OK with domains hosted via no-ip or ddns.

certbot error messages are pretty much self explanatory :

in the first scenario the URL that was used by the authenticator failed with timeout.

in the second scenario the URL that was used by the authenticator failed with HTTP CODE 404 - not found.

These errors incorrectly configured apache vhost :

err 404 suggests certbot has written `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` payload to some other directory than the one that's being served by apache.

timeout suggests that apache is unable to serve contents of `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` within reasonable time limit - probably due to some other missconfig/permissions issues.

Answer (score 0):

See comments: DocumentRoot parameter was incorrectly set

Comment: Please include sufficient information in your answer to make it usable on its own without the comments.